# Windows 7 Not connecting to WiFi

Tags: windows, windows-7, wireless-networking

I have installed Windows 7 enterprise edition on my laptop Dell N4050 and then installed driver Realtek Driver R307625 for connecting to Wifi but it is not connecting to wifi and it says "No Connections are available" . Can anyone please Help. I shall be very thankful.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question, which is what this site is for. Are you actually programming something to connect to wifi?

Answer (score 0):

I know this seems simple, but make sure the Wireless switch on the laptop is in the "On" position. Most Dell computers come with that kill switch located on the front of the computer.

Comment: Yeah i Have turned on the Wifi of my laptop from keyboard. Its indicator light remains on for some seconds and then goes off .@Michael Freeman

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the correct wi-fi driver for your dell?
The model number of your Dell is not enough (You must provide Service Tag Number for dell) because many identical models e.g. n4050 has some differences (Wifi chipset, audio chipset) and so on..

Look on rear side of your notebook and search for the service tag number, then go to dell support - driver page and search the drivers by this tag... it will be the correct wi-fi driver for your dell notebook mainboard!

With best wishes